# Вставка видео в <video> без горизонтальных черных полос

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Вставил видео 16:9 фоном на сайт свой [zasovskiy.ru](https://zasovskiy.ru/). вроде все ок. Но когда я меряю размер экрана на планшет, сразу у видео появляются вертикальные черные полосы сверху и снизу.
Как бы мне это видео сделать адаптивным чтоб растягивалось под размер контейнера и заполняло полностью?

Comment: попробуйте свойство object-fit: cover или изменяйте размеры видео под размеры экрана пользователя (изменение размеров экрана можно отследить с помощью события resize)

Answer (score 0):

У видео, при изменении разрешения под телефон, поставь

```
height: 894px
width: 1241px
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пошли не тем путем. Есть старый, дедовский способ без использования вотчеров которые будут отслеживать размеры экрана. [Вот пример вставки адаптивного видео](https://html5book.ru/adaptivnoe-video/) на CSS. Не надо усложнять, и городить велосипедов, где уже всё придумано.